# Pandas: replace column in dataframe by range function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

There is a Unique Key Column in my csv file and it has in every row the value 1. I want to replace them by real unique values (1,2,3,4,5 ....).

I try:

```
data=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
data['Unique Key'] = data['Unique Key'].replace(1:range(1))
```

but obviously doesn't work ;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data['Unique Key'] = np.arange(len(data))
```

each column in the `pd.DataFrame` can be replaced/ created by a numpy array of the same length.

If you want the keys to start from `1`, you can do

```
data['Unique Key'] = np.arange(len(data)) + 1
```

Comment: Hey friend, how it would be all the columns but the first one?

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a column of `1`s

```
df['Unique Key'] = df['Unique Key'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 2):

May using `reset_index()`

```
data['Unique Key'] = data.reset_index().index+1
```